# ifnull() en laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

Necesito hacer un join en el cual me muestre los valores de algunos campos aunque sean null. Intento usar el ifnull() pero no funciona y busco otra manera de hacer la consulta

Con esto solo consigo losvalores de los campos que no son nulos

```
 $RcTieneNota = Rc::join('nota_pedidos','nota_pedidos.id','=','rcs.idnpedido')
    ->select('idnpedido', 'nota_pedidos.id','estado' , 'rcs.id as idrcs')->get();
```

He probado esto pero me muestra el mismo resultado.

```
DB::Raw('IFNULL( `tble`.`value` , 0 )')
```

Comment: Hola Peta. Puedes poner ejemplos de tus datos y los que quieres obtener y como la consulta que has intentado no refleja lo deseado?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Perdon , https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins